# Sharedpreference byte[] value cleared after app killed via 'Force Stop' or task manager

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences

### Problem

I'm saving a `byte[]` in my shared preferences.  I am able to close the app and reopen it with the value persisting in the Shared Preferences.  When running the app and closing it via the 'Task Manager' or 'Force Close', the Shared Preference value for the `byte[]` is cleared.  I don't understand this because other values persist fine.

This lead me to believe that this was due to some gson or Shared Preference issue with the `byte[]` so I converted it to a String and I still have the issue.

Edit:
I save the data during normal activity usage... after `onCreate()`, for example. It's not during `onPuse()` or `onDestroy()` I forgot to mention this. It would make sense if I did call it here and one or both of those weren't being called on the 'Force Close' scenario.

---

### Shared Preference Code

*Slightly modified to remove app specific implementation and data*

```
private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME = "SharedPreferenceName";

    public static void setSharedPreferenceObjectBase64Encoded(Context context, String key, Object object) throws Exception {
        // Need an editor to update shared preference values
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").create();
        String encodedKey = Base64.encodeToString(key.getBytes(), 0, key.getBytes().length, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String stringObject = gson.toJson(object);
        String encodedObject = Base64.encodeToString(stringObject.getBytes(), 0, stringObject.getBytes().length, Base64.DEFAULT);
        editor.putString(encodedKey, encodedObject);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static Object getSharedPreferenceObjectBase64Encoded(Context context, String key, Class<? extends Serializable> objectClass) throws Exception {
        // Need an editor to update shared preference values
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").create();
        String encodedKey = Base64.encodeToString(key.getBytes(), 0, key.getBytes().length, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String encodedObject = prefs.getString(encodedKey, null);
        if (encodedObject == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("encodedObject is null : No shared preference exists for key.");
        }
        String decodedObject = new String(Base64.decode(encodedObject, Base64.DEFAULT));
        if(decodedObject == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("decodedObject is null : Json decoding error.");
        }
        Object resultObject = gson.fromJson(decodedObject, objectClass);
        if (resultObject == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("resultObject is null : Json decoding error.");
        }
        return resultObject;
    }
```

---

### `byte[]` Code

```
public static final String VALUE_KEY= "value.key";

    public static void saveTheValue(Context context, byte[] encryptedPin) {
        try {
            USharedPreferenceManager.setSharedPreferenceObjectBase64Encoded(context, VALUE_KEY, encryptedPin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static byte[] getTheValue(Context context) {
        try {
            return (byte[]) USharedPreferenceManager.getSharedPreferenceObjectBase64Encoded(context, VALUE_KEY, byte[].class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

#### Any input would be greatly appreciated..

Sadly, I haven't been able to make any progress here.  Any thoughts?

---

#### Update:

As per Super-califragilistic recommendation, I iterated through the key/value pairs in the SharedPreferences immediately before retrieving the value.  I was Base64 encoding my key and value values; in order to read the key to ensure the value was in the SharedPreferences I had to use the keys in plain text.  This solved the issue for me as the `byte[]` value was now being retrieved properly.

This seems strange to me but I can use it as a solution.  I would still like to Base64 encode the keys, but it's not incredibly important.

---

#### Current Solution:

Removed the Base64 encoding of the SharedPreference Key for storage and retrieval and the value is now persisting in all cases.

Comment: Why do you need to serialise a byte array with GSON?

Comment: how do you verify that it is cleared? because it is null?

Comment: I verify that it's cleared because it's null, yes. @Super-califragilistic

Comment: @MarcinKoziński I use this generic function to Base64 encode my shared preference entries.  What are your thoughts on doing that with the byte array entry?

Comment: your data is not cleared, your key does not exist, to really verify that your data is cleared use this code `for(Entry<String, ?> en : sharedPref.getAll().entrySet()){
     en.getKey();
     en.getValue();
    }` then if you do not find the key/value pair then you can say that it is, all i can say now is the force close is tempering with your key formation hence the key you retrieve it with is different, `prefs.getString(encodedKey, null);` the second param is if the key does not exist return null, verify and come back or post where you call your save function in your activity or wherever

Comment: can you paste the code which calls the getValue function and when exactly does that happen

Comment: I updated the question text in response to your input.  Your comment guided me to a solution so thank you.  If you could post an Answer with any input on the update above I will award you the bounty.  Thanks! @Super-califragilistic

Comment: but is the key when it forces close the same as when its closed normally? which phase do you save your data? in `onDestroy()` or `onPause()`, the later would have saved you a lot of headache :)

Comment: I save the data during normal activity usage... after onCreate, for example.  It's not during either of those lifecycle callbacks... I forgot to mention that because it would make sense if I did and one or both of those weren't being called. @Super-califragilistic

Comment: please try it override `onPause()` create some flags globally `private boolean saveHasOccured = false;` _global variable_and
    `private boolean completedSaveInPause = false;` _//this might be redundant_ and after you save your data set the first to true and the second to false, in your `onPause()` `if(saveHasOccured && !completedSaveInPause)`then re-save and set the second to true. it will solve your problem

Comment: I'll try.  I have something working now so that's good.  Make an answer and I'll award the bounty.  Thanks! @Super-califragilistic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code `String encodedObject = prefs.getString(encodedKey, null);` means if the *key* does not exist it should return null, hence your key that you are checking does not exist.

To validate if your key/value exist use this code

```
for(Entry<String, ?> en : sharedPref.getAll().entrySet()){
      en.getKey();//key
      en.getValue();//value
}
```

you could stop that from happening `override` `onPause()` in the `Activity` or `Fragment` and call `saveTheValue(Context context, byte[] encryptedPin)` if you detect you need to save data or have already tried saving data eg.

```
private boolean forceSaveInOnPause= false;//global variable

//in your saving method
....//after you save
forceSaveInOnPause = true;

//in your onPause of Activity
if(forceSaveInOnPause){       
   //re-save
   forceSaveInOnPause = false;
```

*but since you already have a solution scratch all that :)*

Answer (score 1):

Try once with `editor.commit(`) **instead** of `apply()`, see if that works

Comment: It doesn't change the result.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Base64.NO_PADDING instead of Base64.DEFAULT both while reading and writing may solve the problem.

Comment: I gave that a try and had the same result, the value did not persist.  Thanks for the suggestion.